# I am downloading the attachments via REST API in postman. I am getting response as below but I would like know which format it is?

Tags: attachment, httpresponse, postman

We are providing service to a external system, they need to convert the response to a .xlsx file. They are asking about the format.can any one help me in this?[[image: This Is the response I am getting 1]

Answer (score 0):

An `xlsx` file is in the Microsoft [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) format. Basically, you first start by decompressing it, as you would a [ZIP file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)). Then, you read the XML files.

Comment: Thank you for your response @sfdcfox. I kindly ask if you could provide me with step by step procedure to convert the "Office Open XML" response to a actual file. Your prompt response and input would be highly valuable to me, thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: @KCompany The file in the screenshot is an XLSX file. What are you trying to do with the file?

Comment: Yes @sfdcfox ,the screenshot is an XLSX file,  I just want to let the external system know , how to process the response and download it as a file(xlsx).

Comment: @KCompany It's still unclear to me what it is that you're trying to do. Which system is calling which? What does it mean to "process" the file? The entire thing is just vague.